# How make Total cart without "location.reload();"

Tags: javascript, function

i have a problem
In my cart, i want to recalculta the amount total off quantity and price
without using

```
    location.reload();
```

You can find here a bit of my code to understand how i created all my elements

```
    let productLocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("products"));

      let cartItems = document.getElementById('cart__items');


      /*This Function is here because of the unknown number of products in the cart       **
      **so i can reuse the creation of all elements if i need                             **
      **All the JS elements have their own description to make the code more understandble*/
      const cartProducts = (productStorage) => {
        console.log(productStorage.product);
        //------Create constant article who gonna contein all my elements------

        let article = document.createElement('article');
        article.classList.add('cart__item'); 
        article.setAttribute( "data-id", productStorage.id);

        let cartDivImg = document.createElement('div');
        cartDivImg.classList.add('cart__item__img');

        let cartImg = document.createElement('img');
        cartImg.setAttribute('src', productStorage["imageUrl"]);
        cartImg.setAttribute('alt', productStorage["alt"]);

        let cartDivContent = document.createElement('div');
        cartDivContent.classList.add('cart__item__content');

        let cartDivContentTitle = document.createElement('div');
        cartDivContentTitle.classList.add('cart__item__content__titlePrice');

        let cartName = document.createElement('h2');
        cartName.textContent = productStorage.name;

        let cartColorName = document.createElement('h2');
        cartColorName.textContent = productStorage.color;

        let cartPrice = document.createElement('p');
        cartPrice.textContent = productStorage.price + " €";

        let cartDivSettings = document.createElement('div');
        cartDivSettings.classList.add('cart__item__content__settings');

        let cartDivQuantity = document.createElement('div');
        cartDivQuantity.classList.add('cart__item__content__settings__quantity');

        let cartQuantityP = document.createElement('p');
        cartQuantityP.textContent = "Qté : ";

        let cartQuantityInput = document.createElement('input');
        cartQuantityInput.setAttribute("type","number");
        cartQuantityInput.setAttribute("name","itemQuantity");
       
        cartQuantityInput.classList.add('itemQuantity');
        cartQuantityInput.setAttribute("min","1");
        cartQuantityInput.setAttribute("max","100");
        cartQuantityInput.setAttribute("value", productStorage.quantity);
      
        let cartItemDelete = document.createElement('div');
        cartItemDelete.classList.add('cart__item__content__settings__delete');
       
        let CartDeleteP = document.createElement('p');
        CartDeleteP.textContent = "Supprimer";
        CartDeleteP.classList.add('deleteItem');
        

        //Create all the elements
        article.appendChild(cartDivImg);
        cartDivImg.appendChild(cartImg);
        article.appendChild(cartDivContent);
        cartDivContent.appendChild(cartDivContentTitle);
        cartDivContentTitle.appendChild(cartName);
        cartDivContentTitle.appendChild(cartColorName);
        cartDivContentTitle.appendChild(cartPrice);
        cartDivContent.appendChild(cartDivSettings);
        cartDivSettings.appendChild(cartDivQuantity);
        cartDivQuantity.appendChild(cartQuantityP);
        cartDivQuantity.appendChild(cartQuantityInput);
        cartDivSettings.appendChild(cartItemDelete);
        cartItemDelete.appendChild(CartDeleteP);
        cartItems.appendChild(article);

      }

    if (productLocalStorage === null){
        emptyCart();
      } 
      // Loop "forEach" who create all the elements i need in my cart
      else{

      productLocalStorage.forEach(productLocalStorage => {

          cartProducts(productLocalStorage);
      });

    }
```

```
      let products = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("products"));

      function removeItem() {

        let removeBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".deleteItem");

        for (let i = 0; i < removeBtn.length; i++) {
          removeBtn[i].addEventListener("click", (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();

            let articleSupp = removeBtn[i].closest("article");
            
            articleSupp.remove();

            calculateTotal();
            totalArtQte();
            deleteItemSelected(i);
            alert("This item will be delete from your cart !");
            location.reload();
            
            // Actualising the total amount of item in the cart    
          });
          //This Function is here to remove my item in my local storage
          function deleteItemSelected(index) {
            products.splice(index, 1);
            localStorage.setItem("products", JSON.stringify(products));
          }
        }
      }
```

And here is my remove function
as you can see, i try to recall my `calculateTotal()` and my `totalArtQte()` function
to recalculate the amount total off quantity and price, but my function are only recall
if i use `location.reload();` is it normal ? Do you know what can i do ?
I have to use only JavaScript

Thank you for those who gonna read / answer to my question

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to call whole thing again or `location.reload()`. try to find the events when you want to re-calculate the cart. e.g. on

1. new item add
2. updated existing quantity
3. delete items

```
function getProductById(id) {
  let index = productLocalStorage.findIndex( x => x.id == id );
  return productLocalStorage[index];
}

// on new item
function addProduct(product) {
  cartProducts(product);
  productLocalStorage.push(product);
  // update your cart total/whatever by looping through "productLocalStorage"
}

// on quantity change
cartQuantityInput.addEventListener('change', function($event) {
  let product = getProductById(productStorage.id);
  product.quantity = $event.target.value;
  // update your cart total/whatever by looping through "productLocalStorage"
});

// on delete
let deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
deleteButton.innerHTML = 'Delete';
deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function deleteProductEvent($event) {
  productLocalStorage = productLocalStorage.filter(function( product ) {
    return product.id !== $event.target.parentElement.getAttribute('data-id');
  });
  this.removeEventListener('click', arguments.callee, false);
  $event.target.parentElement.remove();
  // update your cart total/whatever by looping through "productLocalStorage"
});
```

PS: make sure your UI, "productLocalStorage" variable and localstorage are in sync.
this will be much easier if you implement this with MVC/MVVM framework like Angular